# Change Ghost Blog's Default Routing

Tags: routes, blogs, ghost-blog

Is there a way to change the default routing in Ghost?

I have created a blog using the ghost platform and changed the default theme from Casper to Ghostion. I then created four static pages about me, my portfolio, blog, and resume. Everything is working as it should.

Here is the problem Ghost by default passes all the blog articles to the index.hbs file. I would like to change this and have them passed to a custom blog.hbs file then when the user navigates to the /blog slug  have the server serve the blog.hbs file instead of the default for static pages. Essentially, I want to move all blog post to the page dedicated for my blog instead of having them displayed on the home page of the site. I hope what I'm trying to achieve is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is not possible without modifying huge chunks of Ghost's core code, but it might be possible in future versions when plugin support arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this would be a great feature added in future versions.

Comment: Do you have any idea when this will be on the roadmap for Ghost?

Comment: @Salman Ghost plugins, or "apps" how they call them, have been on the roadmap for a long time. I haven't been following the development recently, looks like there's still a lot to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in Ghost 2.0. You can change the default routing if you use Ghost 2.0.

Here is some documentation detailing the  configuration: https://docs.ghost.org/docs/dynamic-routing