# How to change Ghost Routing to make a landing page first

Tags: pagination, ghost-blog, ghost

I am building a Ghost Theme at the moment and I am having trouble swapping the blog for the home.

I went and created a post called "news", then change it to a static page, so I can access the slug. Then I created a "page-news.hbs" and it worked fine.

The problem is that when I add {{pagination}} everything breaks. I get a 500 with error

```
[page-news.hbs] pagination data is not an object or is a function
(/Users/lulato/Desktop/DD/DESKTOP/ghost_exper/jagag_exp/node_modules/ghost/core/server/helpers/pagination.js:14:23)
```

I'm also running the home.hbs. Not sure if that's relevant.

I checked an earlier version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254950/change-ghost-blogs-default-routing) but it was from 2014.

Comment: There is no point in adding a pagination to a single post. Paginations are meant to be on pages which have lists like index.hbs

Comment: Yeah but I want to have the blog on a different tab, what would be the approach about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by blog? blog post. Please be more clear. The clearer you will be, the faster I will be able to help

Comment: If I was making a business website, the blog would not necessarily be on the main page. What is the best solution to have the blog not be the "/" page?

Comment: I can't get you. What do you mean by term "blog"? Is it the post list that is generally shown in home page or it is a single post.